# Calling a Camel route endpoint in the main class

Tags: java, apache-camel

I created a Camel route with a endpoint `direct:getRestFromExternalService, and when I try to use this endpoint in a main method inside another class I get an exception

> Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-WMLI118067-61025-1493883025815-0-2]

and

> No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://getRestFromExternalService]. Exchange[ID-WMLI118067-61025-1493883025815-0-2]

This is the route class:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    // Create the camel context for the REST API routing in Fuse
            CamelContext contextFuseAPI = new DefaultCamelContext();

            // Start the route inside the context to listen to the ActiveMQ
            contextFuseAPI.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    from("direct:getRestFromExternalService")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
                        .to("<external API URI>");
                }
});
}
}
```

And this is the Class with the main method that calls this route:

```
public class FuseApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext contextFuseAPI = new DefaultCamelContext();

    contextFuseAPI.addRoutes(new MyRoute());

    contextFuseAPI.start();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    ProducerTemplate template = contextFuseAPI.createProducerTemplate();

    Object result = template.requestBody("direct:getRestFromExternalService", null, String.class);


    Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(contextFuseAPI);
    String response = ExchangeHelper.convertToType(exchange, String.class, result); 
    System.out.println("Response : "+ response);        

    contextFuseAPI.stop();


}

}
```

I tested the main method without the ProducerTemplate and Object lines and it runs. Is there a way to call the requestBody with an endpoint from a route implemented in a different class?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was that the context was created both in the route class and in the main method class.